# How to add literal line - that contain $ signs - to a file, if line does not appear in file already?

Tags: bash

Given the following **literal** line (namely, `$'s` are *not* introducing variables):

```
if $var-with-dollar-and-space == 'local2' and $msg contains 'Disp' then /path/to/file
```

I have to check if that line appears in a file (exactly as is), and if not - to add it to the file.
I tried many variations of escaping characters - but cannot get it right.
Following is an attempt at an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (not working):

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

LINE_TO_ADD_IF_ABSENT="if \$var-with-dollar-and-space == 'local2' and \$msg contains 'Disp' then /path/to/file"
ESCAPED_LINE='if $var-with-dollar-and-space == \'local2\' and $msg contains \'Disp\' then /path/to/file'

LOG_FILE='/tmp/mcve.log'

if [[ ! -e $LOG_FILE ]]; then
  touch $LOG_FILE
fi

if [[ -w $LOG_FILE ]]; then
  $( fgrep -q "$ESCAPED_LINE" ${LOG_FILE} )
  ret=$?
  if [[ $ret != 0 ]]; then
    echo $ESCAPED_LINE >> $LOG_FILE
  fi
fi
```

**Can you suggest an amendment (or a different approach), that will enable me to create a bach script that will add the line at the top to the file, if the line - as is - is not included in the file?**

### Edit:

In response to @Charles' and @David's comments, following is an amended MCVE and the results of its running:

```
$ cat /tmp/mcve.sh
#!/bin/bash -xv

line_to_add_if_absent='if $var-with-dollar-and-space == \'local2\' and $msg contains \'Disp\' then /path/to/file'
escaped_line='if $var-with-dollar-and-space == \'local2\' and $msg contains \'Disp\' then /path/to/file'

log_file="/tmp/mcve.log"

if [[ ! -e $log_file ]]; then
  touch $log_file
fi

if [[ -w $log_file ]]; then
  fgrep -q ${line_to_add_if_absent} ${log_file}
  ret=$?
  if [[ $ret != 0 ]]; then
    echo $escaped_line >> $log_file
  fi
fi

$ /tmp/mcve.sh
#!/bin/bash -xv

line_to_add_if_absent='if $var-with-dollar-and-space == \'local2\' and $msg contains \'Disp\' then /path/to/file'
escaped_line='if $var-with-dollar-and-space == \'local2\' and $msg contains \'Disp\' then /path/to/file'

log_file="/tmp/mcve.log"

if [[ ! -e $log_file ]]; then
  touch $log_file
fi

if [[ -w $log_file ]]; then
  fgrep -q ${line_to_add_if_absent} ${log_file}
  ret=$?
  if [[ $ret != 0 ]]; then
    echo $escaped_line >> $log_file
  fi
fi

/tmp/mcve.sh: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/tmp/mcve.sh: line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file
$
```

Comment: What's the extra `$( )` around the `fgrep` supposed to do? Also, note that you're missing a bunch of quotes -- consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: (As another aside: all-caps names are in a namespace used for variables meaningful to the shell itself; whereas the namespace with at least one lower-case name is reserved for application use; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that defining a shell variable overwrites any preexisting like-named environment variable).

Comment: @boardrider Could you elaborate on what exactly doesn't work when you run the code in the question?

Comment: See _Edit_ in response to @Charles' and David's comments.

Comment: BTW, `${foo}` is **exactly** the same as `$foo`; it adds no correctness benefit whatsoever (except when concatenating the expansion's result with an immediately-following string which starts with a character valid inside of a shell variable name). `"$foo"`, by contrast, prevents string-splitting and glob expansion, which has very immediate and direct impacts on correctness.

Comment: If you want to be able to use backslashes to escape single quotes in a string where parameter expansions are not honored, btw, consider `$''` (which is to say, ANSI-C-style) quoting, as in the following: ```line_to_add_if_absent=$'if $var-with-dollar-and-space == \'local2\' and $msg contains \'Disp\' then /path/to/file'```. If you use standard single quotes, backslashes are literal inside them.

Comment: ...see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings for more re: said quoting style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works fine in practice:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

line_to_add_if_absent="if \$var-with-dollar-and-space == 'local2' and \$msg contains 'Disp' then /path/to/file"
log_file='/tmp/mcve.log'

[[ -e $log_file ]] || touch -- "$log_file"

if [[ -w $log_file ]]; then
  if fgrep -q -e "$line_to_add_if_absent" "$log_file"; then
    : "do nothing here; line is already present"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$line_to_add_if_absent" >>"$log_file"
  fi
fi
```

The only change I had to make was removing the unnecessary/useless `ESCAPED_LINE`, and using the variable with literal contents. (Quoting has also been fixed; `echo $ESCAPED_LINE` is unreliable, and `echo` was replaced with `printf`, as backslashes in `echo` statements have undefined behavior; see also the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html))

Comment: Many thanks, @Charles, for the excellent answer and the useful URL.